# Adding a click event to a list of iterations with ngfor

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ngfor

I'm developing an app and so far this is what I have achieved. I have my individual flights displaying horizontally in a list that I can scroll through:

[image]

What I want is that when I click on an individual flight, its details will pop up / be shown on the screen. So my next step is figuring out how to add a click event to these flight iterations so that the selectFlight method will be called.

My Code:
flight-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Flights </h3>
<div>
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let flight of flights" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module flight">
                <h4>{{flight.number}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

flight.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'flight-viewer',
    templateUrl: 'app/flight-viewer.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/flight-viewer.css']
})
export class FlightViewerComponent  {
    name = 'FlightViewerComponent';
    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;
    flights: Flight[];
    selectedFlight: Flight;
    flightToUpdate: Flight;

    constructor(private service: FlightService) {
        this.selectedFlight = null;
        this.flightToUpdate = null;
        this.fetchFlights();
    }
    flightSelected(selected: Flight) {
        console.log("Setting selected flight to: ", selected.number);
        this.selectedFlight = selected;
    }
```

flight.row.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[flight-row]',
    templateUrl: 'app/flight-row.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/flight-row.css']
})
export class FlightRowComponent {
    @Input()
    flight: Flight;
    @Output()
    onFlightSelected = new EventEmitter<Flight>();
    @Output()
    onFlightUpdating = new EventEmitter<Flight>();
    name = 'FlightRowComponent';

    selectFlight() {
        console.log("Just selected ", this.flight.number, " for display");
        this.onFlightSelected.emit(this.flight);
    }
```

Somehow I need to add a click event like this : (click)="selectFlight() on to each of the li elements (each individual flight)..

Can someone help me with this? I'm new to developing in angular with HTML & CSS.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
old flight-viewer.html

```
<!--
<h3>{{errorMessage}}</h3>
<flight-selected [flight]="selectedFlight"></flight-selected>
<table *ngIf="stateValid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Departure Time</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Arrival Time</th>
            <th>&lt;!&ndash; Select link &ndash;&gt;</th>
            <th>&lt;!&ndash; Update link &ndash;&gt;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr flight-row
            [flight]="current"
            (onFlightSelected)="flightSelected($event)"
            (onFlightUpdating)="flightUpdating($event)"
            *ngFor="let current of flights"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div *ngIf="flightToUpdate">
    <flight-update [flight]="flightToUpdate"
                   (onFlightUpdated)="updateFlight($event)"></flight-update>
</div>
-->
```

flight-row.html:

```
<td>{{flight.number}}</td>
<td>{{flight.origin}}</td>
<td>{{flight.departure | date}}</td>
<td>{{flight.destination}}</td>
<td>{{flight.arrival | date}}</td>
<td><span (click)="selectFlight()">Select</span></td>
<td><span (click)="updateFlight()">Update</span></td>
```

Do i need something in my flight-viewer.html such as onFlightSelected ="flightSelected($event)"?

Answer (score 0):

> flight-viewer.html:

```
<div>
<ul class= "grid grid-pad">
    <a *ngFor="let flight of flights" class="col-1-4">
        <li class ="module flight" (click)="selectFlight(flight)">
            <h4>{{flight.number}}</h4>
        </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

> flight.row.component.ts:

```
@Component({
selector: '[flight-row]',
templateUrl: 'app/flight-row.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/flight-row.css']
})

export class FlightRowComponent {
    @Input()
    flight: Flight;
    @Output()
    onFlightSelected = new EventEmitter<Flight>();
    @Output()
    onFlightUpdating = new EventEmitter<Flight>();
    name = 'FlightRowComponent';

selectFlight(flight) {
    console.log("Just selected ", this.flight.number, " for display");
    this.onFlightSelected.emit(this.flight);
}
```

**you have to pass that parameter of flight in selectFlight(flight)  and the function will accept this parameter and return that particular info of flight**

All the best.
for any query write your comment

Comment: nothing happens when clicking. I have edited my old code in to the question to show you how it worked before when all the flights were in a table and there was a select button beside each to bring up the data.